# How to hide bottom nav bar in flutter on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-widget, flutter-bloc

I want to hide bottom bar from another page bottom bar is in page1 and I want to hide it after scrolling in page 2

So I have bottom navigation bar 
On 
page1.dart

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IndexedStack(
            index: _currentIndex,
              children: _widgetOptions,
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                height: 59,
                width: 80 / 100 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),*/
                child: Card(

                  elevation: 10,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildItem(FeatherIcons.home, 0),
                      Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        _buildItem(FeatherIcons.bell, 1),
                        notification==0?SizedBox(height: 0,width: 0,):
                        Positioned(
                            top: -1.0,
                            right: -1.0,
                            child: new Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Icon(
                                  Icons.brightness_1,
                                  size: 12.0,
                                  color: base,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ))
                      ]),
                      _buildItem(FeatherIcons.plusCircle, 2),


                      /*  Container(
                        width: 50,

                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 5,
                          child:Icon(FeatherIcons.plusCircle,color: Colors.white,),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),*/
                      /*  Icon(
                          FeatherIcons.plusCircle,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 30,
                        ),*/
                      _buildItem(FeatherIcons.messageSquare, 3),
                      _buildItem(FeatherIcons.user, 4),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

And _widgetOptions

```
List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
feed(),notific(),postpagee(),Text(
  'Index 2: School',
),
profilee()  ];
```

How to hide bottom navigation which is made with container in above code.. from another page on scroll listview
I have seen other examples buy they jus put all code to get even listview in same page and tht not possible when your app has multiple functions in same page